# ServiceStack sliding expiration

Tags: servicestack

I'm working over a small project core, which was born more than 1 year ago.

I have to enable sliding expiration and I wanted to know if it was now supported out-of-the-box in SS.

Do somebody know if there is a way to add the sliding expiration without having to mark all the POCOs with the attribute?

Comment: That code reported in the link was created upon your specification as in the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857921/how-to-advance-the-session-timeout-in-servicestack
BTW the question was not about that code, but about the sliding expiration implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The filters in [ServiceStack's Request Pipeline](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations) support the same signatures where anything that can be done in a [Request or Response Filter Attribute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Filter-attributes) can also be done in a [Global Request or Response Filter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-and-response-filters).

The [sliding Sessions example](http://teadriven.me.uk/2013/02/14/sliding-sessions-in-service-stack/) that uses `[SlideExpiration]` Response Filter Attribute, e.g:

```
public class SlideExpirationAttribute : ResponseFilterAttribute
{
    ...
    public override void Execute(
        IHttpRequest req, IHttpResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        var session = req.GetSession();
        if (session != null) req.SaveSession(session, this.Expiry);
    }
}
```

Is just re-saving the Session so it gets resaved with a new Session Expiry, this can instead be done in a Global Response Filter with:

```
GlobalResponseFilters.Add((req, res, dto) =>
{
    var session = req.GetSession();
    if (session != null)
        req.SaveSession(session);
});
```